# C++: Using function pointers with member functions

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to pass a function to another function as a parameter, and they both happen to be member functions of the same class.

I'm getting a weird error and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Here are my functions:

```
void myClass::functionToPass()
{
   // does something
}

void myClass::function1(void (*passedFunction)())
{
   (*passedFunction)();
}

void myClass::function2()
{
   function1( &myClass::functionToPass );
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
   cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void(__thiscall myClass::*) (void)' 
   to 'void(__cdecl*)(void)'
```

So what gives?  I feel like I've tried every variation to try to get this to work.  Can you even pass function pointers for member functions?  How can I get this to work?

Note: Making functionToPass static isn't really a valid option.

Comment: The error message gives you all necessary info to fix the problem.

Comment: Using `boost::function` may be easier than using function pointers. You'd have to check whether that should be `boost::function<void(void)>` (in which case `function2` should bind `this`) or `boost::function<void(MyClass&)>` (in which case `function1` should pass `*this`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass function pointers to member functions. But that is not what your code is doing. You are confused between regular function pointers (`void (*passedFunction)()` is a regular function pointer) and pointers to member functions (`&myClass::functionToPass` is a pointer to a member function). They are not the same thing and they are not compatible.

You can rewrite your code like this

```
void myClass::function1(void (myClass::*passedFunction)())
{
   (this->*passedFunction)();
}
```

Now your code is using pointers to member functions, but of course this means you won't be able to pass a regular function pointer.

Comment: Makes sense!  I don't have a chance to test this out until tomorrow but if it works out I'll definitely give an accept.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others, your mistake is in the type of the function pointer being passed.  It should be `void (myClass::*passedFunction)()`.

Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.goingware.com/tips/member-pointers.html) on using pointers to member functions in C++.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that you were passing the function pointer to a member function of the same class.  I thought you were passing it to some other function, in which case you would need an object of `myClass` to actually call the function pointed to by `passedFunction`.